# element wise "contains" in Python

Tags: python

Say I have an array:

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.random.randint(0, 5, 20)
```

then `arr>3` results in an array of type bool with shape (20,). How can I most efficiently do the same thing with the "contains" operator? The simple

```
arr in [2, 4]
```

will result in "The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()". Is there another way than

```
np.array([ x in [2, 4] for x in arr])
```

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`np.isin`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.isin.html):

```py
import numpy as np
arr = np.random.randint(0, 5, 20)
np.isin(arr, [2, 4])
```

Output:

```py
array([False,  True, False, False, False,  True, False, False,  True,
       False, False, False,  True, False, False,  True, False,  True,
       True,  True])
```

The function returns a boolean array of the same shape as your input array named `arr` that is `True` where an element of `arr` is in your second list argument `[2, 4]` and `False` otherwise

Answer (score 1):

pandas offer this via, pd.Series, or np.ndarray, but so far I don't know any other array module provide this.

```py
a = pd.Series([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])
print(a.isin([0,3]).any())  # returns True
print(a.values.isin([0,3]).any()) # returns True  (a.values is np.ndarray)
```